# Event receiver not firing Document Library

Tags: development, document-library, sharepoint-addin, event-receivers, visual-studio-2013

I have a local development environment in my VM.(SharePoint server 2013 SP1,Visual Studio Ultimate 2013-update3). I'm trying to add an event receiver to a document library on ItemDeleting.  Deleting a document in the document library should add an item to my custom List 'Log'.  Here is my code:

Event.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Security.Permissions;
  using Microsoft.SharePoint;
  using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
  using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

  namespace SharePointProject1.EventReceiver1
  {
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{

    public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        //base.ItemDeleting(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Log"];
                SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
                newItem["Title"] = properties.ListItem.Name;
                newItem["DateAndTime"] = System.DateTime.Now;
                newItem["Action"] = "Item Deleted";
                newItem.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
   }
```

Element.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
       <!-- <Receivers ListTemplateId="101" > -->
       <Receivers ListUrl ="Doclib"
      <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiver1ItemDeleting</Name>
       <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
         <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
         <Class>SharePointProject1.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
       </Receiver>
       </Receivers>
       </Elements>
```

Feature1.Template.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
       <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        </Feature>
```

I deployed the solution on the SP site and activated the feature.

So I have two questions:

1. When I use the code: ListTemplateId="101" , I do not get an error, But the event receiver is not firing. When I delete the "Log" list is not updated. Am I missing something?
2. If I give the Document library name in the ListUrl, I get the following error:

> "An error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The list
>   "Doclib" doesn't exist.  Please fix the ListUrl attribute."

Please advise on the right approach.
Why is my event receiver not firing?

Comment: listtemplateid = 100

Comment: I guess 100 is for list and not document library.Here i have document library.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why an `EventReceiver` would not fire. According to my experience, one of the sneakiest reasons is that you are using a `dll` from another project, but, from the same solution. And if you didn't add the assembly for when the solution is deployed the `EventReceiver` using it would not fire because the `dll` would not load.

If you haven't tried that out yet, it's like this:

In your solution, double-click `Package` -> Then Add the assembly for the `dll` you want to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One issue I've had with event receivers is them not attaching to a list properly.  As a result I've had to attach them manually through feature receivers `Activate` function with this code

```
<SPList Object>.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "SharePointProject1.EventReceiver1");
```

With event receiver code something like this

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  EventFiringEnabled = false;
  /*

    Your Code Here

  */
  base.ItemDeleting(properties);
  EventFiringEnabled=true;
}
```

With this approach, attaching is done via code, and Elements.xml is not needed, and the event receiver is attached only to a specific SPList Object.

It is a good idea to have it removed via code on feature deactivate if the list is not being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a different approach .Rather than specifying list id or name in ELement.xml you can specify same thing in the code

```
public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
     if(properties.ListItem.Title="Name of your list")
{
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Log"];
                SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
                newItem["Title"] = properties.ListItem.Name;
                newItem["DateAndTime"] = System.DateTime.Now;
                newItem["Action"] = "Item Deleted";
                newItem.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```